# Capture linux terminal in PHP

Tags: php

my question is how to get output of terminal in php? I mean i want to create a website where users could view what's happening in the terminal. I want to "capture the terminal" and then echo it in PHP. I don't know how to really explain this so if you didn't quite understand me, please ask me what you didn't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Read php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: @Rainmx93 I know that function shell_exec exists but it wont return me the result of full terminal

Comment: what do you mean full terminal?

Comment: I want the terminal output to be written to me in sequence. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: @Rainmx93 i want something like live preview of terminal

Comment: Try searching for "interactive web command line" and you will find some things. It is not easy to set up and security is a big concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you are working for is "terminal screencasting", that is the term to google ;-)

Some solutions :

- **script and scriptreplay** linux commands

  type `script /var/www/log/history_log.txt` for starting logging what you type in the shell

you then type anything command ; to stop script, type exit and press [Enter].

And the log will be available in the file history_log.txt

More informations here https://www.tecmint.com/record-and-replay-linux-terminal-session-commands-using-script/
and here https://www.linux.com/learn/using-screen-remote-interaction

- **ShowTerm** :

There is also the solution ShowTerm, more informations here : https://www.tecmint.com/showterm-io-a-terminalshell-recording-upload-and-share-tool-for-linux/

- **tty2gif** :

more informations here, https://github.com/z24/tty2gif

- **asciinema** :

web based solution (with linux tool to install) : https://asciinema.org/

Comment: Happy to have helped you! ;-)